# What are the advantages and disadvantages of SQL versus NoSQL in data science?

Tags: databases

In which situations would one system be preferred over the other? What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of relational databases versus non-relational databases?

Comment: This question is far too broad. It may be salvaged by restricting the question to a particular use case.